# JBoss localhost only war

Tags: tomcat, jboss, war

Is it possible to deploy N wars (where N is > 1) to JBoss (or Tomcat I suppose) such that one of the wars is a localhost only war?

For clarification I have two wars:

War-1 :  Contains my web application
War-2 : Contains Solr (or any indexing service really) that should only be accessed via War-1 (the application) because it lacks "real" security

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, you can not define specific interface bindings for deployments. 
All deployments are accessible on the interface that the server is bound to.

However, you could setup container managed security for one of your applications.
See [JBoss Security Realms](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Security+Realms).
Or you could run multiple application server instances.

Another solution is to set up a reverse proxy using a http server (NginX, Apache Httpd or the like) managing your access restrictions.